IOptions doesn't load settings from json
This is my appsettings.json file:
{
  {
  "User": {
      "Name": "Marco",
      "Level": "developer",
      "Password": "54321"
  },
  "Robot": {
    "Ip": "192.168.2.244",
    "Port": "3111"
  },
  "PLC": {
    "Ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "Port": "5000"
  }
}

Then in my code I wrote a class MyAppSettings:
namespace IOptions_test
{
    public class MyAppSettings
    {
        public UserSettings User { get; set; }
        public RobotSettings Robot { get; set; }
        public PlcSettings PLC { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserSettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class RobotSettings
    {
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlcSettings
    {
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
    }
}

And I have this in my program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace IOptions_test
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            // Configure services and load configuration
            // ConfigurationBuilder is used to load configuration from a settings.json file.
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            // Create a new ServiceCollection, which is used for Dependency Injection (DI)
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            //This registers the Form1 type as a transient service, which means a new instance will be created every time it's requested.
            services.AddTransient<Form1>();

            // Build the ServiceProvider (DI container) from the configured services
            using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Retrieve the main form (Form1) from the DI container
            var mainForm = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Form1>();

            Application.Run(mainForm);
        }
    }
}

I try to inject the settings. The problem is that in the MainForm.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace IOptions_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Private field to hold the application settings (MyAppSettings)
        private readonly MyAppSettings _settings;

        // Constructor for Form1 that accepts IOptions<MyAppSettings> to get the settings injected by DI
        public Form1(IOptions<MyAppSettings> settings)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Cast the IOptions object to ensure it's the correct type
            var options = settings as IOptions<MyAppSettings>;

            // Access the Value property to get the actual MyAppSettings object
            _settings = settings.Value;

            // Set the text of label1 to display user and IP information from the settings
            label1.Text = $"User: {_settings.User.Name}, Robot IP: {_settings.Robot.Ip}, PLC IP: {_settings.PLC.Ip}";
        }
    }
}

the _settings remain null and it throws an exception

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[IOptions_test.MyAppSettings]' while attempting to activate 'IOptions_test.Form1'


IOptions doesn't load settings. It's used to map already loaded configuration settings into objects based on the actual setting names. In this case the names don't match. There's no root "MyAppSettings" section

Have you checked the Options pattern documentation? If you want to load options from a specific section instead of one matching the type name you can use Configure<MyOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(customName))

i modifid the code a bit but it still give me another exception when i Retrieve the main form (Form1) from the DI container

The code never calls Configure<MyAppSettings>(). Without this, there's no IOption<> middleware at all. I suggest going through the documentation example instead of just trying things. Instead of trying to configure individual middleware libraries, create a generic host like that shown in in all examples. builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args); is enough to set up configuration, logging and DI, using appsettings.json by default

BTW that Cast the IOptions object to ensure it's the correct type is meaningless. as doesn't ensure anything and settings is guaranteed to be the correct type. You got an exception precisely because the DI container couldn't provide a valid settings object

You actually did not register anything that would resolve to IOptions<MyAppSettings>.
In order to correct that you need to add following registration code:
services.Configure<MyAppSettings>(config);

You need to install Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions nuget package for that.
Here's result of the changes:

